# Does Visual Studio 2012 (in any of its editions) show unused includes?

Tags: c++, refactoring, visual-studio-2012

Say I have a `*.cpp/.h/.hpp*` file with  `#include <map>` in it but I do not use anything defined or referenced by `map` header file. I want VS to tall me a warning or something that I do not use data from file I included.

So does Visual Studio 2012 (in any of its editions) show unused includes? (answer required shall include simple - YES/NO)

Answer (score 4):

These sort of answers drive me up the wall. Every other language does this. Any C++-able linker does it. It's easy:

1. Compile everything, producing, among other things, a symbol table for that module
2. Link it.

   - Anything that's used, but not defined, already generates an `undefined external` error.
   - Everything that's defined, but not used, should generate an `extraneous external definition` warning. While you're at it, group these by source file, and only generate the warning if no symbols in that module are referenced.
3. Either

   - show a warning: "Hey, man, you're not really using this thing... so... whatever, man. Cheers", or
   - enable a context menu options, like "remove unused includes," to clean it up.

For a static language, you have a symbol table.
When linking, you can see what items in that table are used.
You can offer an option to at least *highlight* everything that's NOT used.

If you really need to, build the thing, go through the above steps, and rebuild *after* removing potentially unused references. If it explodes, roll it back.

There are a hundred ways to solve this problem. The fact that none of the IDEs out there apparently do this is surprising.

At the very least, make it a "helpful hint" option. It's not the job of the compiler to do the programmer's job. It's the job of the IDE to do as much of the programmers job as possible, with the mutual understanding that ultimate responsibility lies with the human in the chair.

***Source** I used to write C compilers for a living.*

Answer (score 3):

There is no known way to tell if you don't use anything from an include file. It's an unsolved problem except in utterly trivial cases.

Consider the following include file:

```
int x;
```

How could you tell if `x` was or wasn't referenced? The compiled output that included that file might link to another object file that accesses `x`. The compiled object file might be linked in more than one way at more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tell if an include file is unnecessary is to comment it out or remove it entirely, and see if the code still compiles. This is a process that would be easy to automate.

Comment: You mean the best way to tell if an include file is *necessary*. This cannot tell you if an include file is unnecessary. (For example, say the include file has `int x;` in it. The code will still compile if `x` isn't referenced in that C++ file. But it won't link if it's referenced in another one. So the include is necessary even though the code compiles without it. Another example is if the include file `#define`s something that changes the behavior of later code. This is very common.)

Comment: Old question, but @DavidSchwartz I think, in this case, it's safe to assume that by "compile" Mark meant "build." Six of one...

Comment: Isn't best practice not to rely on indirect includes? If one want to use `std::vector` one should include `<vector>` even, if that header is already included by a previous one and the project would still compile. So - in my opinion - just see if the code compiles is not really a good solution.